# Balance tables with CSS

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-tables

I have these tables that get created by Parsedown, a PHP based Markdown parser that does its job well.

The end result of tables in a browser is abominable though, I've included a screenshot to show what I mean.

[image: Abominable table balancing]

In this two column table, I expect the left column to be significantly smaller than the right one. Normally I would just manually fix a table like this, but since the table is generated by Parsedown I can't.

I also cannot use `table-layout: fixed` globally since I have to accommodate for tables of all shapes and sizes.

Has anyone a solution, or just a place to start looking for one?

Just to be complete here is the generated HTML for this table:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Small content</td>
            <td>Large content</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Small content</td>
            <td>Large content</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Small content</td>
            <td>Large content</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The full computed CSS in Chrome:

[image: Computed CSS]

Comment: can you share css or check in inspector what is causing this?

Comment: Could you provide the current css of the table?

Anyways, check the [column-span](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_column-span.asp) property

Comment: Add css please.

Comment: Added computed CSS! And found the answer (see below).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know readability can be increased easily by adding `width: 1%;` to all `th` and `td` in a table. You can try the css snippet below. Dont know if your restrictions are very high but if you can add classes to your tables I highly recommend using the [bootstrap css for tables](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables).

```
table {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table th,
table td {
  width: 1%;
  padding: .5rem;
  vertical-align: top;
}

table thead th {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Comment: Ahhh there it was! The `td` elements had an inherited width of 70% causing them to do wacky stuff. Forcing a width of 1% or auto does the trick.

Comment: Would love to see the fixed result :)